# What is the recommended minimal epsilon for double?

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to create a Gauss Eliminator in C. For this, from time to time, I need to check whether a matrix is numerically singular: if a certain number (double) is very very very small.

My problem is, that if I try to do this:

```
if(0 == matrix->items[from]){
        fprintf(stderr,"Matrix is still singular after attempting pivot. Exitig.\n");
}
```

This will never yield true. Because of the inaccuracy of double, it will never be exactly 0. However, when trying to run the program, cases like this fill up the numbers with inf or NaN, depending on whether multiplying or dividing with it and its combinations.

In order to filter these, I would need something like this:

```
#define EPSILON very_small
// rest of the code
if(matrix->items[from] < EPSILON){
     ...singular
}
```

What is the recommended value for this EPSILON? Is it the absolute accuracy of double, or maybe a bit larger value?

By the way, which would be better, defining it as a macro as above, or using it like:

```
const double EPSILON = ...;
```

Sorry if I'm not being clear enough, English is not my native language.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Please do not write `if (0 == matrix->items[from])`, it's really ugly. And modern compilers will complain if you accidentally use assignment instead of comparison, so this is no longer a "*good*" practice.

Comment: There is only one correct value: `DBL_EPSILON`.

Comment: @Olaf Why is that the only correct value?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I believe `if (VALUE == VARIABLE)` (e.g. `5 == i`) is called a *yoda statement*, and it's not necessarily ugly, but it sure gets your code laughed at.

Comment: Values smaller than DBL_EPSILON are too small for double precision to pick up.  IEEE double precision values have 16 digits of precision, so this is 1.0e-16.

Comment: @immibis: Because that's what the platform provides.

Comment: @duffymo: There is no reuirement for an iomplementation to use IEEE floating point.

Comment: The value of `epsilon` may depend on the context: not how close *can* you get, but how close do you *need*.

Comment: Why is     if (0 == matrix->items[from]) ugly?

Comment: Which header do I have to include for DBL_EPSILON? Is it float.h?

Comment: DBL_EPSILON is that value at which 1 + DBL_EPSILION minus a bit == 1.0. It's too small to be used as a general epsilon for sloppy equality tests. I use FLT_EPSILON, but more because the name is available and it's obvious why I'm using it than through rigorous testing.

Comment: `int main (void) { printf("%g %g\n", __DBL_EPSILON__, __DBL_EPSILON__/2); }` => `2.22045e-16 1.11022e-16`. The value is only meaningful in the vincity of 1.0, it has absolutely no special meaning around 0.0, what we are talking about in this question. So, the value is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Olaf "It's what the platform provides" is a dumb reason. The platform also provides `DBL_MAX`. Does that mean `DBL_MAX` is the only correct value? No, it does not mean that. Likewise `INT_MIN` is not the correct value even though it is also provided by the platform. Nor is `__STDC__`.

Comment: @immibis: I OP asked "what is the maximum value of a `double`", what would be wrong about `DBL_MAX`?

Comment: @Olaf The OP didn't ask "what is the maximum value of a `double`". S/he asked something that has nothing to do with either `DBL_MAX` or `DBL_EPSILON` or `__STDC__`.

Comment: @immibis: OP asks for the minimum **epsilon**, which is exactly `DBL_EPSILON`. It was not me bringing the other constants into discussion.

Comment: @WhiteWolf Post is missing  how `matrix->items[from]` relates to matrix singularity.  `matrix->items[from] < EPSILON` certainly appears to be the wrong way to test for matrix singularity.  Consider posting code that generates `matrix->items[from]` and why nearest to 0.0 of the elements constitutes singularity.

Comment: @Olaf But the question uses the word "epsilon" to mean something *other* than what "epsilon" means in `DBL_EPSILON`.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to check whether a matrix is numerically singular

Usually this is detected by preventing `double` overflow.

```
// Check if 1.0/determinant will overflow.
if (fabs(determinant) <= 1.0/(0.99*DBL_MAX)) {
  Handle_Singular_Case()
} else {
  one_over_det = 1.0/determinant;
}
```

Using `DBL_EPSILON` (example: 2e-16) is usually the *wrong* solution.  `double` math needs *relative* comparisons to insure good calculations far way from 1.0 magnitude.

```
// Rarely the right thing to do.
#define EPSILON DBL_EPSILON
if(fabs(matrix->items[from]) < EPSILON){
```

Yet this is very context sensitive [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913943/what-is-the-recommended-minimal-epsilon-for-double/42914824#comment72927288_42913943).

---

Yet OP's real problem is certainly here: "when trying to run the program, cases like this fill up the numbers with inf or NaN, depending on whether multiplying or dividing with it and its combinations.".  Various techniques can be used to avoid this issue like doing elimination with [partial pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element).

To address *that* issue, best to post code and sample data.

Comment: Good observation about structuring the algorithm for numerical stability in general, and about partial pivoting for this purpose in particular.  Converting math to good programs is not nearly as simple as converting formulae to the syntax of the language of choice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True.  The receptive calculation of matrix operations hide various pitfalls.  I had a bug for years in partial pivoting code as in finding the maximum element, code used `abs()` and not the correct `fabs()` - and insufficient warnings enabled.  Error did not truly manifest itself until all the |elements| were less than 1.0 - a div by 0.0 occurred later.

Comment: What is the point of `(1.0*DBL_EPSILON)`? Can multiplying by one actually do anything?

Comment: @rici The `(1.0*DBL_EPSILON)` could have been explained.  Often the epsilon needed is some small factor near 1.0, maybe in the range 0.5 to 2.0.  As with many such problems the value is application specific.  Like the `(0.99*DBL_MAX)`, which could have been `(0.999999...*DBL_MAX)` to insure the value is just smaller to avoid some round-off error in the inverse calculation.  For the 2nd half of the answer, I'll remove it as its is a subtle enhancement that takes away from the gist of the answer.

Comment: I thought it was some c++ subtlety that I had missed :-) If the idea was to allow a way to choose a number near `DBL_EPSILON`, the implication would be that there is something about `DBL_EPSILON` which makes it appropriate for this purpose. But its actual meaning has no relationship, so it is just some arbitrary smallish number, which could just as well have been 2**-69 or 2**-42. (At least, I believe that to be the case,  and your comment that this is "usually wrong" suggests we agree.)

Comment: The program does full pivoting, this filter is needed to detect exactly singluar matrices. Like when two rows are exactly the same.

Comment: "filter is needed to detect exactly singular matrices" would look for 0.0.   Minimal epsilon would be for _nearly_ singular matrices.  Perhaps expand on your goal.